# how do i increase the font size of the text inside it and how can i provide more data on Flatlist each item?

Tags: react-native

I want to increase the size of the Flatlist item text. 
Also second part to this question is, is there a way I can display more information not just 2 lines of text

Below here is the code for my component.

```
  return (
            <FlatList
              data={this.props.properties}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <ListItem onPress={()=>navigate('editProperty',{item})}
                  roundAvatar
                  title={`${item.name} `}
                  subtitle={`${item.address}, ${item.city}`}
                  style={styles.row_alternate}
                  containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
                />
              )}
              keyExtractor={item => item._id}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
              ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
              ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
              onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
              onEndReachedThreshold={50}
            />
    );
```

Here is the css class that I used.

```
  row_alternate: {
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        // backgroundColor: '#fad0c4'
        // backgroundColor: '#66a6ff',
    }
```

Comment: What's your <ListItem> component looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `titleContainerStyle` and `subtitleContainerStyle`, which are props of `ListItem`, in order to provide styles for these elements, and use `fontSize` to adjust the font size.

EG `titleContainerStyle = {styles.titleContainerStyle}`

In terms of adding multiple lines, i believe you can only add sub-title and titles at the moment. A work around would be to pass in a custom-view component as your sub-title, and add information to that as you wish. Ive typed some example code below.

```
<ListItem
    title={`${item.name} `}
    subtitle={
      <View>
        //ENTER WHATEVER YOU LIKE HERE.
      </View>
    }
```

I believe the default is a simple `Text` component, and not too sure how expandable the subtitle is.

You can read up on Lists further here: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/lists/